# Unable to Download plugins from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, devops

I have installed Jenkins 2.263.1 on mac os with Java Version 1.8.0_77. When i try to download the plugins from GUI or jenkins CLI i get the error

```
Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor66.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1890)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1885)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1884)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1457)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1280)
```

Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to load https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/git-client/3.5.1/git-client.hpi to /var/root/.jenkins/plugins/git-client.jpi.tmp
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1287)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to download from https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/git-client/3.5.1/git-client.hpi

I understand it is related to Certificates but how do i resolve it? Where can i find the cert for jenkins update site which i can add to JAVA keystore? Also is there a workaround to this issue as it is just on my local

Thank you

Comment: Doea this help: [Jenkins 2.235.3: New Linux Repository Signing Keys](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2020/07/27/repository-signing-keys-changing/)?

Comment: This does not apply to Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

if you get validate certifacate issue while downloading the jenkins plugins just
do check your time settings in your linux environment .
check time ---> date cmd
update the time ---> date s "date month year hr:mm:ss"

try to restart your jenkins and download plugins